# Windows 10 balloon tooltip popup from an Asp.Net Website

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, ajaxcontroltoolkit, windows-10-desktop

Is it possible to create a Windows 10 taskbar balloon tooltip using Asp.Net in C# or in jQuery? I couldn't find this in Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most up to date browsers support the [Web Notifications API](https://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/). This allows you to ask the browser to show operating system notifications from JavaScript Code.

See the [Microsoft documentation on web notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/device/web-notifications-api) for some sample code.

See [which browsers support the web notifications API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications). Edge, Chrome and Firefox support this natively, for Internet Explorer you need to install a [plugin](http://ie-web-notifications.github.io/) to support this.

Comment: This is great but I couldn't run the code... Here is my downloaded page: http://hqtunes.com/balloon_tooltip/

Comment: @mrbengi it is difficult to help since you keep editing that web page

Comment: Okey I won't change

Comment: Two problems that are there in the current version: 1. You need to add `type="button"` to the button. Otherwise it will submit the form it is part of making the page reload. 2. In the javascript, you execute `document.getElementById` while the page is loading. You can only execute that code when the document has finished loading. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/807903/101087 on how to execute code when the document has finished loading.

Comment: In fact, I have copied and pasted the same code which you have linked in the answer. But thank you, I will ask a new question for this